# как работает код на питоне?

Tags: python

```
ware_1 = input("Введите название товара и его стоимость через пробел: ")

cost_1 = [int(i) for i in ware_1.split() if i.isdigit()]
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как код выделяет числа из строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
cost_1 = [str(i) for i in ware_1.split() if i.isdigit()]
```

Такая конструкция называется списковое включение. Выполняемые в ней операции можно поделить на несколько этапов:

1. `ware_1.split()` - разделяет строку на слова
2. `for i in` - итерирует по каждому слову (последовательно перебирает эти слова), где i назначается новое слово на каждом этапе итерации
3. `if isdigit(i)` - это условие, выполнение которого необходимо для включения в список: здесь оно проверяет, является ли слово числом. И если не является, то исключает его из перебора
4. `str(i)` - преобразует каждое "число" (которое и так имеет тип строки, так что здесь без особого смысла) к строке

Comment: не совсем понимаю что значит "где i назначается конкретное слово на каждом этапе итерации"

Comment: прошу прощения, вместо str(i) там должно было быть int(i)

Comment: i - это своего рода локальная переменная в скоупе выражения, которой на каждом шаге итерации присваивается новое слово